# Latest IBC code for residential regarding tempered glass requirement - Philadelphia, Pennsylvania

Tags: windows, safety, glass

In the home inspection report, it was stated that: "a Qualified window contractor to correct as determined necessary the master bathroom window in the shower has no tempered etching. (should have safety glass)"

The location of the current non-tempered glass window is 5'3" from the shower floor.  The window size is 2'10 5/16" x 2' 9 3/4".  The window is original from 2017 brand new construction.  If this requires tempered glass, kindly share with me the specific section in the code where it states this requirement.  Thank you.

Comment: What point on the window is that 5'3" dimension measured to?

Comment: Are you buying this home, selling this home, remodeling, or just hired an inspector for the fun of it?

Answer (score 2):

Maria, unless the IBC has changed since late 2018, your window would only require tempered glass if it were less than 60" at the base, above standing level (floor level), AND measured 9 sq.ft.
You can check it out yourself under "tempered glass requirements in residential bathrooms". Either code has been changed or your inspector didn't read code correctly.